# Can the active release technique help prevent or treat tendon injuries?

Tags: tendinopathy, tendons, physiotherapy

Can the active release technique help prevent or treat tendon injuries?

I have read some pilot studies with small samples sizes (see below), I wonder whether there are more extensive studies, ideally RCTs or SRs.

---

{1} George, James W., Andrew C. Tunstall, Rodger E. Tepe, and Clayton D. Skaggs. "The effects of active release technique on hamstring flexibility: a pilot study." Journal of manipulative and physiological therapeutics 29, no. 3 (2006): 224-227. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16584948  ;https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=1297471980492189395&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22  ; http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0161475406000376

> OBJECTIVE: The aim of this study is to determine if active release
>   technique (ART) significantly increases hamstring flexibility in
>   healthy male participants.
>
> METHODS: Twenty physically active male participants with no current or
>   previous history of lower extremity injury received ART on the origins
>   and insertions of the hamstrings and dorsal sacral ligament. The
>   sit-and-reach test was used before and after treatment to determine
>   hamstring flexibility. Summary statistics were calculated, and pre and
>   post hamstring flexibility scores were compared using a related
>   samples t test.
>
> RESULTS: There was a significant difference between the pre- and
>   posttest groups (mean pre = 35.5 cm, df = 19, SD = 7.56; mean post =
>   48.3 cm, df = 19, SD = 7.07; P = .0015). All 20 participants increased their sit-and-reach scores following the application of ART.
>
> CONCLUSIONS: **This study demonstrated that a single ART treatment
>   increased hamstring flexibility in a group of healthy, active male
>   participants.**

{2} Drover, Janice M., Dominique R. Forand, and Walter Herzog. "Influence of active release technique on quadriceps inhibition and strength: a pilot study." Journal of manipulative and physiological therapeutics 27, no. 6 (2004): 408-413.
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15319764 ; https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=7686360738794548562&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22 ; http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0161475404001010

> Objective
>
> To determine if Active Release Technique (ART) protocols could be used
>   as an effective way to influence strength and muscle inhibition in the
>   quadriceps muscles of athletes with anterior knee pain.
>
> Design
>
> Pilot clinical outcome study.
>
> Methods
>
> The sample consisted of 9 athletes (4 male athletes, 5 female
>   athletes) who were identified as suffering from unilateral anterior
>   knee pain. A Biodex dynamometer and the interpolated twitch technique
>   were used to determine isometric strength and inhibition in the
>   quadriceps muscles, respectively. The treatment intervention consisted
>   of the Active Release Technique treatment protocols for anterior knee
>   pain. The experimental leg and contralateral leg were tested
>   pretreatment and posttreatment, and the experimental leg was tested a
>   third time approximately 20 minutes posttreatment.
>
> Results
>
> Knee extensor moments were calculated by multiplying the moment arm by
>   the forces measured by the Biodex dynamometer. Percentage of muscle
>   inhibition was calculated by dividing the interpolated twitch torque
>   (ITT) by the resting twitch torque (RTT), that is (ITT/RTT*100). A
>   repeated measures analysis of variance (ANOVA) was used to compare
>   pretreatment and posttreatment values for strength and muscle
>   inhibition for the experimental and contralateral knees. The results
>   showed no statistical significance.
>
> Conclusion
>
> **ART protocols did not reduce inhibition or increase strength in the quadriceps muscles of athletes with anterior knee pain.** Further
>   study is required.